# How should display user subscribed documents in SharePoint?

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, subscribe

I want to display a list of subscribed report/document list where  user can check and uncheck for getting refresh when those are updated.

Which approach I can take a list or grid view or check box list or document filtered/ custom view?

Thanks in advance.